# search and replace in VI

Tags: regex, vi

I need to convert '12.22.54' to '12:22:54' in a string below so that it works in MS SQL.

```
cast('14-JAN-14 06.65.22 AM' as datetime),'63.124.79.253');
cast('14-JAN-14 12.22.36 AM' as datetime),'63.124.79.253');
cast('14-JAN-14 22.13.54 AM' as datetime),'63.124.79.253');
```

I tried to open the file in vi and replace like

```
:s/(\d\{2\})\.(\d\{2\}z)\.(\d\{2\})/$1:$2:$3/g
```

But it's not working.  Please help.

Comment: Looks like you have bigger problems - `06.65.22` is not a valid time in any format, and you have what appears to be 24 hour times suffixed with AM.  Is that verbatim from the file or have you redacted it?

Comment: Hi Paul, it's the Oracle datetime and I need to convert it to MS SQL datetime.  If I can convert all the dots to be colons, it works fine.  However the file is too big so I need to replace them using regex.

Comment: I think you are missing my point.  There is no time format on this planet that has more than 60 minutes in an hour, and when you are using AM / PM you cannot have more than 12 hours in the hour column.  Ie, there is no such time as 22:13 in the morning.

Comment: Sorry, I copied & pasted so I just made up some numbers.  The point is how to convert '.' to ':' without affecting the ip address.

This is the original string:

to_timestamp('24-JUL-14 04.48.47.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'63.124.79.253',0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the IP address, I just put spaces around the matching string:

```
:%s/ \(\d\d\)\.\(\d\d\)\.\(\d\d\) / \1:\2:\3 /g
```

Answer (score 1):

`vi` does not use perl-style regular expressions.  You wrote

```
:s/(\d\{2\})\.(\d\{2\}z)\.(\d\{2\})/$1:$2:$3/g
```

but `vi` uses syntax like this (vim and vile accept `\d`, but you said ["vi"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html)):

```
:s/\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\.\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\.\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)/\1:\2:\3/g
```

(Where did the "z" come from?).

The point is that what Perl calls "deprecated" is the POSIX syntax for back references.  Perl, of course, will never be standardized while Larry Wall is around.

Per comment, the OP's intent was to change all lines.  In vi, that is done using the special range `%`:

```
:%s/\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\.\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\.\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)/\1:\2:\3/g
```

One could also use a range explicitly ([`$` is POSIX also](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_02)):

```
:1,$s/\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\.\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\.\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)/\1:\2:\3/g
```

There are other ways to construct the boundaries to avoid IP-addresses.  But with the example given, a blank is enough:

```
:s/ \([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\.\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\.\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\) / \1:\2:\3 /g
```

Likewise, [vim](http://www.vim.org/) and [vile](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.html) accept `\s` for spaces, but POSIX would accept only a literal space (as shown), or a character class `[:space:]`.  Most people find typing <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> less trouble than `[[:space:]]`.

As noted, if you say "vi", others may choose to answer based on standard (POSIX) behavior.  Some editors which can be used in place of "vi" provide extensions to the regular expression syntax.  A quick check shows that [elvis](http://elvis.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/) also supports the Perl-style `\d` and `\s`, while [nvi](https://sites.google.com/a/bostic.com/keithbostic/vi/) (the most standard-conformant of the four) does not.

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas.  It works great but line by line not globally.

I added \sAM in case some ip address falls into the pattern

:s/\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\.\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\.\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\sAM\)/\1:\2:\3/g

Comment: Actually I thought you intended per-line, and assumed the question was about the back-references.  Will add "%" for completeness.